# Directory.GetFiles does not return any file names. What are the causes?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to use c# to iterate over a network share folder containing sub-folders with pdf files within.

I am able to iterate through the sub folders, but no files are found. There are 10 files in the first sub - directory folder "\fileshare\apptest$\docs\Processing\ **Site1**" as an example.

If I can see the files and folders via my windows domain account ( and I placed the files in the folder), shouldn't I also see them when debugging the code below in VS 2022 ?

I am probably doing something incorrect however, here is some sample code.

The first foreach block returns nothing.

The second foreach block returns the folder names, but no file names.

```
using System.IO;

// returns zero file names
foreach (string sfile in Directory.GetFiles(@"\\fileshare\apptest$\docs\Processing\", "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(sfile);

}

// this code block returns the sub-folder names, but no files as all are found
foreach (string sourcedirectory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"\\fileshare\apptest$\docs\Processing\"))
{
    // prints subdirectories
    Console.WriteLine(sourcedirectory);

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourcedirectory))
    {
        // does not print any files
        Console.WriteLine(file); 
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe a problem of rights on the folder..

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as administrator, perhaps using a different account than the one you are using to check if the files are there in Explorer?